# Implementation of a client-side 'require' function compatible with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Having decided to implement all of my Javascript libraries as modules compatible with node.js, I've now put together a simple 'require' function to be used on the client side of things. I do realize that there are already plenty of very good implementations out there of this, but most seem fairly heavy-handed so I'm just opting to go with the "roll-your-own" approach.

Here's my 'require.js' file:

```
/*
    A client-side script loading class designed to be compatible with node.js
*/

function require(filename)
{
    try
    {
        var
            script = null,
            ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(),        
            index = filename.toLowerCase().indexOf('.js');
        if(index <= 0 || index != filename.length - 3)
            filename += '.js';
        ajax.onload = function() 
        { 
            script = this.responseText;
        };  
        ajax.open('GET', filename, false);
        ajax.send();
        return _isolate_script_(script);
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        return null;
    }
}   

function _isolate_script_(_script_)
{   
    return (new Function
    (
        'var exports = {}, module = {exports : null}; ' 
        + _script_ + 
        '; return module.exports || exports;'
    )).call();
}
```

Example module ('example.js'):

```
/*
    Example of a multiple-class export file
*/

exports.metallic = function(value)
{
    return (Math.sqrt(4 + value * value) + value) / 2;
}

exports.inverse_metallic = function(value)
{
    return exports.metallic(-value);
}
```

Example of a module consumer ('main.js'):

```
function main()
{
    var
        example = require('example');
    if(example != null)
    {   
        var
            value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        alert
        (
            'example.metallic(' + value + ') = ' + example.metallic(value) 
            + '\n' + 
            'example.inverse_metallic(' + value + ') = ' + example.inverse_metallic(value)
        );
    }
    else
        alert('Error: cannot load "example"');
}
```

Finally, a basic HTML file that invokes our page logic:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src = 'require.js'></script>
        <script src = 'main.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body onload = "main()"></body>
</html>
```

So my specific question is simply whether or not I've implemented everything correctly, and moreover if the framework and use-cases seem kosher enough?

Comment: This is lightweight in terms of code but heavy-handed in terms of execution. You're using synchronous XHR which will freeze your browser. The reason other solutions seem heavy in terms of coding is because they want to avoid freezing the browser.

Comment: @slebetman: Well, the problem with the async approach is that it just complicates things too much. Since 'require' can't return until it has the data, I would just end up using a 'busy-loop' to wait around for it anyway (and thus blocking). I just can't think of a reasonable way to implement it otherwise. Besides, the fact of the matter is that if XMLHttpRequest really did freeze up for some reason, it would be due to some other serious issue, in any case, right?

Comment: Synchronous Ajax.  Bleeech!  I would never use that.  And, because you aren't using `<script>` tags, you will be blocked from cross origin requests unless they specifically enabled CORS access.

Comment: @jfriend00: I understand the cross-site limitations and I am fine with that. Regarding the synchronous aspect, how else could it be done cleanly?

Comment: @SirGalahad: You may be underestimating how much javascript a modern web app or website use. May be fine in your case for a hobby website but this is not usable in production. In the last 5 years the average website I've worked on load more than 1MB of javascript. Blocking javascript load will make the website stutter. It's worse when your website gets mentioned on twitter or arstechnica

Comment: @slebetman: Again, whenever the 'require' is invoked the caller has to wait anyway (what could it do otherwise?). That said, I may give the busy-loop-with-timeout approach a try just to prevent any potential lockup on older browsers.

Comment: @SirGalahad: People normally wait for javascript to load but while waiting the browser have started to render the webpage. Your approach will show a white page until all javascript is loaded. Also, during this time the browser literally freezes - it won't even allow you to right-click (well, maybe Chrome will). That's why it's not usable in production. Other people don't use a busy loop because that does not work (it freezes everything including the ajax request so the browser will never request the script). What they do instead is use callbacks

Comment: @slebetman: I don't think that's quite right. Since the 'main' function is tied to the body.onload event, it won't get triggered until _after_ the page has completely loaded. And callbacks just don't seem to be the right choice here. I think blocking for at least as much time as specified in a timeout parameter would be reasonable enough. Is that really such a bad idea?

Comment: Like I said, it may be OK for your hobby project but not for websites like Facebook that load more than 1MB of javascript. Facebook for example takes more than 10 seconds (18 seconds on my home connection) to load all their js files. If they did not do it async you'd see a white page for more than 10 seconds.

Comment: @slebetman: Just to reiterate, I have tested this with large files and the pure HTML parts of the page load immediately, so your assertion that the user might see a 'white page' for some extended period just isn't true (unless, perhaps, all of the page loading occurs in the 'main' function, that is).

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are trying to reimplement [Browserify](http://browserify.org/):

> Browsers don't have the require method defined, but Node.js does. With Browserify you can write code that uses require in the same way that you would use it in Node.

If you want to implement a similar thing yourself then take a look at the Browserify source code.

See: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify

Comment: Nice! Yes, that indeed appears to be a very useful library. Much thanks.

Comment: @SirGalahad: The reason Browserify work is because it's not a library (your approach). It's a compiler. It compiles all modules into a single file

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to answer this myself.

The main issue is that older browsers sometimes freeze-up with synchronous ajax requests. Simply launching the entire 'main' function in it's own thread seems to be a good solution for that. That is, if some unforeseen issue arises with loading scripts then the page itself may not be responsive, but the browser should at least be unaffected. In other words, something along the lines of this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src = 'require.js'></script>
        <script src = 'main.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body onload = "setInterval(main)"></body>
</html>
```

As to concerns about throughput, I've now tested this with huge amounts of data (~100 MB) and it appears to make little difference on performance as to whether the code was loaded with a script tag or via the ajax call. All major browsers on two different operating systems and the results were pretty much the same. So unless I see convincing evidence to the contrary I'm just going to assume this to be the rule rather than the exception.

All that said, I'm certainly still open to any comments or criticisms that may be.

Comment: `setInterval` does not run code in its own thread. You need web worker for that

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I was rather ignorant of that fact. Web workers don't seem to be universally available at this point either so I may need to rethink my strategy altogether here. Back to the old drawing board...

Answer (score 0):

If you want module caching as well try this:

```
let parent = "";
let cache = {};

/**
 * Load a JavaScript text synchronously.
 *
 * @param url The url.
 */
function cludge(url) {
    /* resolve and check */
    if (parent !== "")
        url = new URL(url, parent).href;
    let map = cache[url];
    if (map !== undefined)
        return map;
    map = {};
    cache[url] = map;

    /* load and execute */
    let back = parent;
    try {
        parent = url;
        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', url, false);
        request.send();
        let fun = new Function("exports", "require", request.responseText);
        fun(map, cludge);
    } finally {
        parent = back;
    }
    return map;
}
```

But the name resolution is not as elaborate as in nodejs.